# May I use your dictionary? Of course , you ______

Tags: modal-verbs, exam-questions

In this sentence can I simply reply with "Yes, you may"
because I corrected it from the model answer it was answered "Yes, you can". "Yes, you may" was excluded.

Can I use "may" in short replies?

Comment: Who wrote this test? For the last 65 years, the response I got to 'May I _do something_? was 'Yes', or 'Yes, you may', or 'You may'. In fact, if children in my entry class aged five said to the teacher 'Can I be excused/go to the toilet/etc?', she would say 'You can, but you  may not'.

Comment: Yes, "may" is correct and natural, along with "can". The exam is wrong

Comment: I think the 'may' (formal) versus 'can' (less formal) thing is settled these days - you can say either, and 'may' is a minority usage. It is ugly and clumsy to mix them in the question and the response, so the 'model' answer is severely wrong.